# Dynamic Library Function Call

Tags: c, linux, dlsym

I have the following code which simply loads the library test.so from the current directory and executes the `version` function within that library. What should be returned is a string. What is instead returned is junk from the stack(a pointer location maybe?). Does anyone have any idea why the following code would be failing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    void *handler;
    char *(*version);
    char *error;

    handler = dlopen("./test.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handler){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    dlerror(); //Flushes any existing error

    *(void **)(&version) = dlsym(handler, "version");

    if((error = dlerror()) != NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%s\n", version);
    dlclose(handler);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the declaration:

```
char *(*version); // this is not a function pointer
```

to:

```
char *(*version)(); // but this is
```

then, change the line:

```
printf("%s\n", version);
```

to:

```
printf("%s\n", version());
```

Answer (score 3):

dlsym just returns a function pointer. You still need to actually call it, which you can do by casting the (void*) to a function pointer of the appropriate type and calling that.

Comment: Casting `version` to `(char *)version` still returns junk.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your code:

The declaration of `version`: it is a pointer to a pointer to char in your code, which led you to a weird conversion in:

```
*(void **)(&version) = dlsym(handler, "version");
```

Instead use a pointer to function returning pointer to char, like so:

```
char *(*version)();
```

and use a regular assignment:

```
version = dlsym(handler, "version");
```

You are not calling the function, when you print the result. In C, writing just the function name returns its address, so `version` and `&version` are equivalent. Your code should be like:

```
printf("%s\n", version());
```

Comment: The ugly aliasing-rules-violating pointer cast OP used actually comes from the POSIX documentation. :-( However, it should not be used. Your version without casts is also broke, however; `void *` does not convert to function pointer types. The only correct solution is: `char *(*version)(); void *tmp = dlsym(handler, "version"); memcpy(&version, &tmp, sizeof version);`

Comment: Thanks to you I actually read the manual;). Though now I don't see the problem with the POSIX example.

Comment: The problem is in the examples here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html The rationale explains why they wrote they didn't write the example the obvious way (ISO C requires the compiler to generate a diagnostic for the data-pointer-to-function-pointer cast), but fails to address the fact that they violated the aliasing rules by accessing an object through the wrong type (and thus the compiler could optimize it out or break the code by reordering the read/write). The `memcpy` version is the only safe way I know to write it, if you want to suppress the warning.